# Sending a destination link into database and then echoing it out

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, path

I have a products page where I output my products via a while loop like this...

```
<?php   
// Loop to display all products
foreach($products as $id => $product) {
?>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="productpiccontainer">
            <?php echo "<img src='productpics/". $row['img'] ."' alt='Product Pic'>"; ?>
        </div>      
        <p><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'] . "</a>"; ?></p>
        <p> <?php echo "$" . $product['price']; ?> </p>                                     
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

As you can see in the code, I am linking the view product page as a standard page and showing the product clicked upon by the product id. Now what I want to do is create different View Product pages, so I can showcase different kind of products.

The way I insert my products into my database is through an admin page I created. I enter the product id, name, category etc through this and then it is sent to my database and outputs on the product page.

Now, my idea was to create a new input field in my admin page that is an option field that has multiple 'View Product' templates. I was wanting to send the link that is what is shown on my products page into my database ..

```
<?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'] . "</a>"; ?>
```

That I could then have the option with each additional product that was being created and echo that out onto my product page.

So it would be something like this..

```
<p><?php echo "$product['option']" . $product['name'] . "</a>"; ?></p>
```

The issue I am having is I am unable to figure out how to send the link..

```
<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>
```

into my database to even attempt to echo this out.

I'm trying to send it is a field, just like I do all of my other data in the page..

```
<select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
    <option name="notSelected">Not Selected</option>
    <option name="viewproduct_type" value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
    <option name="viewproduct_type" value="Option">Option</option>
</select>
```

How can I get this link to send or is there a better option to do this? I want to keep this automated as much as possible, hence why I'm doing it like this.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but you just want to save a link into the database? What exactly is problematic about that?

Comment: @cen Whenever I try to send the query, I get errors now allowing me to INSERT the link.

Comment: Could not INSERT: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near './viewProduct.php?view_product=$id', '', '')' at line 1

Comment: Maybe because your link contains quotes. Try escaping it.

Comment: @cen I tried taking out the quotes and the query ran, but it only inserted the letter a. I wrote it like this... <option name="viewproduct_type" value=a href=./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id>Standard</option>

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have html code as a value in another html element which is just asking for trouble. If you really wanted to pull that off I suggest you read about [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities). 
Your second problem is that you are apparently not escaping your inserts. Read about [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

The easiest thing to do in your case is to simply pass IDs to your select list and then combine the link with the ID just before the insertion. There is no need to store a full link inside your select list values.

Sample code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="ASD" method="post" action="mysqli.php">
    <select name="link">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test", 3306) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST["link"])) {
    $save="./viewProduct.php?view_product=".$_POST["link"];
    $save = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $save);
    $r = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO links VALUES('".$save."')");

    if ($r === false) echo "Failed ".mysqli_error();
    else echo "Success";
} 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I output that though? I'm still confused how the link is going to be added into my database? I'm going to have two different links.  I want the ability with every new product I add to distinguish which product template I am using (link). Then output that.

Comment: For each product you save the type as an int or a full string, if you want to change templates based on that type you can use an additional URL parameter, ex: `?view_product=$id&type=$product['type']`. Then you can simply switch the display in view_product.php based on the `$_GET['type']` value.